# How to implement startActivityForResult

Tags: android

In my app I create two activities and I want to get input from the second activity and use it in the first activity, I use startActivityForResult but there is a problem in it!

That is the code of first activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i=new Intent("net.naif.action.GETDATA");
            startActivityForResult(i,77);
        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityForResult (int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    if (requestCode ==77 && resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
        String msg =data.getStringExtra("text");

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this for the second:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      final EditText t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s=t.getText().toString();
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.putExtra("text",s);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Android studio notify me that is the method ( `protected void onActivityForResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` is never used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the method is named [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), not `onActivityForResult`.